# Почему обработчик события вызывается больше 1-го раза?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-events

На странице есть пачка динамических инпутов, их может быть от 0 до 90 штук. Появляются на странице из результатов `ajax` запроса на сервер. Выглядят примерно так:

```
<input required type="number" min="0" class="form-control insel settings-input" value="25"  data-skim-level="min" data-key="qty" data-denom-key="5">
```

На них навешен обработчик `blur`, выглядит так:

```
$('#skimming-level-tab').on('blur','.settings-input',function () {
    var skimming_level_data = $(this).data('skim-level');
    var qtyOrValue_data = $(this).data('key');
    var denomKey_data = $(this).data('denom-key');
    var dependentInput, insertedValue;
    if (qtyOrValue_data === 'qty') {
        dependentInput = $("[data-skim-level='"+ skimming_level_data +"'][data-denom-key='"+ denomKey_data +"'][data-key='value']");
        insertedValue = ($(this).val()/100)*parseInt(denomKey_data, 10);
    }
    else {
        dependentInput = $("[data-skim-level='"+ skimming_level_data +"'][data-denom-key='"+ denomKey_data +"'][data-key='qty']");
        insertedValue = ($(this).val()*100)/parseInt(denomKey_data, 10);
    }
    dependentInput.val(insertedValue);
    var minInput = $("[data-skim-level='min'][data-denom-key='"+ denomKey_data +"'][data-key='value']");
    var skimInput = $("[data-skim-level='skim'][data-denom-key='"+ denomKey_data +"'][data-key='value']");
    var maxInput = $("[data-skim-level='max'][data-denom-key='"+ denomKey_data +"'][data-key='value']");
    if(validateInputs(minInput, skimInput, maxInput)) {
        return
    }
    else {
        alert('Error');
    }
});
```

Теперь вопрос: почему `alert` выскакивает больше 1-го раза, в то же время если заменить `alert` на `console.log` - отрабатывает 1 раз?
Если быть точным - то ровно столько раз, сколько на странице на данный момент инпутов.

Comment: А кем #skimming-level-tab приходится этим динамическим инпутам?

Comment: @KirillKorushkin Папой/Мамой приходится.

Comment: попробуй заменить alert на `console.log`

Comment: @Grundy - а это объясняет: "столько раз, сколько на странице на данный момент инпутов"?

Comment: @Grundy А вот `console.log` отрабатывает только 1 раз

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется нужно проверять currentTarget

```
  if(event.currentTarget !== this ) {
     return;
  }
```

Comment: нет, не нужно *(1 символ нужен...)*

Answer (score 1):

`<телепатия>`

> Появляются на странице из результатов ajax запроса 
>   ... 
>   столько раз, сколько на странице на данный момент инпутов

Потому что Вы вызываете код

```
$('#skimming-level-tab').on('blur','.settings-input',function () { ... });
```

и, таким образом, навешиваете новый обработчик каждый раз, когда создаете новый инпут.

`</телепатия>`

> Как избежать такого поведения?

Так. Мне бы хотелось, чтобы мы сначала убедились, что мое объяснение - правильное. Поставьте какой-нибудь `alert` или `consoloe.log` непосредственно перед вызовом `on`:

```
alert("attaching blur handler");
$('#skimming-level-tab').on('blur','.settings-input',function () {
```

Comment: `$('#skimming-level-tab').on('blur','.settings-input',function () { ... });` запускается раз, в `$(document).ready(function(){ ... });`.

Comment: @Klimenkomud Это не соответствует, поведению, описанному в вопросе. Вы чего-то не замечаете в Вашем коде. Создайте пример, воспроизводящий наблюдаемое явление.

Comment: С ваших слов получается, что на каждый элемент каждый раз вешается новый обработчик события? Как избежать такого поведения?

Comment: @Klimenkomud посмотрите дополнение в ответе

Comment: Перед вызовом `.on` `alert` вылетает 1 раз.